# aui:validator tag not working in jsp page

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-aui

I'm working on liferay version 6.1.1 , Below the code given for liferay aui validator , which not working on jsp pages

Syntax type 1 -

```
<aui:input name="fname" type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" id="fname">
```

Syntax type 2 -

```
<aui:input name="fname" type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" id="fname" >
        <aui:validator name="required"></aui:validator>
        </aui:input>
```

I need the solution very soon , Thanks in advance

Comment: Running through the Liferay Cookbook thier example seems to work fine. For the inputs they do not declare the id, value, or class and they set the validator as self closing. Your syntax doesn't look like it should break anything. Just to be sure you may strip it down to just the name and type in the tag and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I did not manage either until I added in portlet.xmL:

```
<init-param>
    <name>add-process-action-error-action</name>
    <value>false</value>
</init-param>
```

This might help,
Gerbrand

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please have look into following links

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/01/form-validation-in-liferay.html

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/12/liferay-aui-validator.html

Answer (score 0):

Check javascript error in your page.
inspect element then go to console, generally this error happen only if there is any error in javascript in our page. 
Resolve that javascript error and they try.
I also faced same issue, I did lots things but just remove the error of javascript and then it is working prefectly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Make that your input field is in an aui form

```
<aui:form ...>
  aui .... input fields here
</aui:form>
```

Read [this](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/39663934)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I fixed it by putting a name to the **aui:form** containing the **aui:input.**

I don't know why validators requires a form name, yet it works.

`<aui:form action="${URL}"  name="putANameHere" cssClass="form-inline">`

I hope it works for you